# Result after finishing an intent

Tags: android

I have a service that is running which will bring up an activity (`MyActivity1`). If you normally start my application, `MyActivity2` is the default activity that is launched.

This is the behavior that i am getting

1. Service shows a notification in the notification bar
2. User clicks on the notification
3. MyActivty1 is launched
4. They finish doing whatever in this activity and I call `finish()` to end the activity
5. They are brought back to my application and `MyActivity2` is shown.

In step 5, the behavior I would like is for them to return to the main screen rather than open my activity. How could this be achieved?

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExchangeConfigActivity.class);
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
CharSequence from = getString(R.string.app_name);
CharSequence message = "Exchange Account - Setup Required";
Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"Message", System.currentTimeMillis());
notif.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), from, message, contentIntent);
notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
nm.notify(id, notif);
```

Comment: "main screen" means the Android Home-Screen?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that MyActivity2 is being pushed to the background when MyActivity1 is launched. Then when MyActivity1 is finished it pops MyActivity2 back.

If you're referring to the Android Home screen, all you would have to do is finish() MyActivity2 when it's out of focus, like in onPause().

Comment: This would change the behavior of the application, because the application would end every time the screen is turned off or another application comes to the foreground.

Comment: then just finish() it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to start a new task stack in your notification intent:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

That way, when the user backs out of the notification, the'll go back to the homescreen.

Comment: I added this to the intent, but behavior doesn't change. This still returns to my application.